# Having issue with the concept of extra semi-colon at the end of for loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I was writing a code to insert an element at the end of the linked list. However without using the semi-colon at the end of for, I'm unable to get the list updated properly, what is the significance of this semi-colon and how is this affecting my code?

```
public void insertAtEnd() throws IOException {
        LinkedList node=new LinkedList();
        System.out.println("Enter an element");
        int value=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        node.setData(value);
        LinkedList p,q;
        for(p=head; (q=p.getNext())!=null; p=q); 
            p.setNext(node);
    }
```

Comment: It's good practice to put the body of the for loop inside curly braces. If you ever do anything else inside the loop, the presence of curly braces will make sure the code executes inside rather than outside the loop.

Comment: What is the purpose of that loop?

Comment: Note that the extra indentation of the last line is highly misleading! it suggests that line should be executed each iteration, while it should only be executed after the loop completes. If you remove the semicolon, node would become the second element, and the third, and the fourth, etc.

Comment: @MarkChorley true, but here the body is supposed to be empty, so a semicolon is fine.

Comment: @Oebele it's good practice to do it *even if the body is supposed to be empty*. It is much easier to miss the `;` than it is to miss a pair of braces. It's a rare enough thing to write that tools like [errorprone](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/EmptyIf) forbid it entirely.

Comment: @AndyTurner fair enough, I can understand that. Especially considering the amount of people posting answers claiming that the semicolon must be removed.

Comment: all of this should be improved for readability with a comment explaining the loop

Answer (score 7):

The semicolon means that the statement below won't be executed until the loop has exited. Your case, the loop is taking p to the end of the list (the last element) and then the next statement is assigning its next value to the new element

Answer (score 2):

Well, the way it is constructed right now as `for(p=head; (q=p.getNext())!=null; p=q);`, the for loop has an empty body. The variables `p` and `q` through the `p.getNext()` and `p=q` assignments are updating. Then it is executing the `p.setNext(node);` a single time.

**EDIT**: As to why the code is working *with* the semi-colon, it is because you are advancing the variables p and q over the list. While the `for` loop with the empty body is fine, I think traditionally one sees a `while` loop.

The indentation of the `p.setNode(node);` makes it appear as if the statement were related to the `for` loop, but it really isn't, as the goal is to find the end of the linked list by iterating over it.

(note: others made similar points while I was typing this answer)

Comment: not entirely correct - it does change the value of `p`, which is essential to the code functioning correctly.

Comment: @Oebele, you are correct, and I meant to state that there is no body of the for loop, and thus the `p.setNext()` was not being called.

Comment: Alright, now it is correct. Upvoted, if only so it appears above the incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1):

it needs to be removed, it is causing it to do nothing in the loop.

The loop will execute the next single block of code after the loop. Either one statement, or one { }  code block.

In this case, you have one statement `;`, so it "executes" and does nothing, and then will call your `p.setNext(node);` after the loop ends.

```
public void insertAtEnd() throws IOException {
        LinkedList node=new LinkedList();
        System.out.println("Enter an element");
        int value=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        node.setData(value);
        LinkedList p,q;
        for(p=head; (q=p.getNext())!=null; p=q)
            p.setNext(node);
    }
```

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong. The purpose of the loop is to find the last element, and add `node` as its next element. If you remove the semicolon, `node` would become the second element, and the third, and the fourth, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is essentially transforming what you appear to want to do because of your indentation:

```
for(p=head; (q=p.getNext())!=null; p=q)
{
    p.setNext(node);
}
```

into the following:

```
for(p=head; (q=p.getNext())!=null; p=q)
{
}
p.setNext(node);
```

So with the semicolon your loop is executing nothing at every iteration. Then, after it has finished executing, you're running `p.setNext(node);` exactly once.

Usually you can avoid this problem in the future by explicitly writing your curly braces as I have done in these two code segments. It is unclear exactly which code segment you are trying to accomplish right now.

Comment: No. This is wrong. Your first snippet sets the object `node` as the second, third, fourth etcetera element, causing an exception, I forgot which one precisely, OutOfMemoryException I think?

Comment: @Oebele I was only addressing OP's actual question: explaining how the semicolon effects the code. I don't fully understand what he is trying to accomplish as-is. Do you believe my edit is more clear now?

Comment: It's better. I doubt he wrote this code himself though, as it appears he does not understand the code. Note that claiming that in the second snippet the loop does nothing is also misleading, as the value of `p` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    //statement(s)
}
```

When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:

1. The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, 
   as the loop begin
2. When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
3. The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

In your case, the loop is taking p to the end of the list (the last element) and then the next statement is assigning its next value to the new element